# when Countdown timer = 0, alert button or submit form

Tags: javascript, php

When my timer count to `00:00:00`
`alert('Get Result')` button or submit the form

I cant even alert message in response.php.

This is Where I select the duration from database

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    $duration=$row["duration"];
}

$_SESSION["duration"]=$duration;
$_SESSION["start_time"]=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$end_time=$end_time=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+'.$_SESSION["duration"].'minutes',strtotime($_SESSION["start_time"])));

$_SESSION["end_time"]=$end_time;
```

This is response.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$from_time1=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$to_time1=$_SESSION["end_time"];
$timefirst=strtotime($from_time1);
$timesecond=strtotime($to_time1);

$differenceinseconds=$timesecond-$timefirst;
if($differenceinseconds<0){
    // This is for when timer smaller then 0 then = 00:00:00
    $differenceinseconds=0;
    echo "TIME UP<br>";
//I try to alert a simple message here, and dint work. Why is this happen
}
echo gmdate("H:i:s",$differenceinseconds);

?>
```

Here is the javascript in quiz page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x =setInterval(test,1000);

    function test()
    {
        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET","response.php",false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
</script>
```

The display timer tag

```
<div id=response class=timer style=font-size:30px></div>
```

The Form name and the button

```
<form name=myfm method=post action=quizz.php>
    <input type=submit name=submit value='Get Result'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP should only get the difference in time. That means that PHP will always output a format of `HH:mm:ss`, and no other text or values, which you then get in JavaScript. Ensuring that the output is always the same, unless you're using encoded arrays, means that you can design your code to expect the values you always send.

```php
$differenceinseconds = $timesecond - $timefirst;
if ($differenceinseconds < 0){
    $differenceinseconds = 0;
}
echo gmdate("H:i:s", $differenceinseconds);
```

You can then check that value after you fetch the values in JavaScript, since you now know that the only thing printed by your `response.php` is a time in the format of `HH:mm:sss`.

```
function test() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "response.php", false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    var response = xmlhttp.responseText;

    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = response;
    if (response == "00:00:00") {
        alert("Time's up!");
    }
}
```

If you want to submit the form as well, add a `submit()` within the condition `if (response == "00:00:00") {`.

```
document.getElementsByName('myfm')[0].submit();
```

Comment: It can alert the Time's up, but it can't submit the form


`if(response == "00:00:00"){

     document.getElementsByName('myfm')[0].submit();
    }

`
when time's up it just stuck there, do we have a way to alert and get Result Button in the alert message?

Comment: If the alert shows as it should, then there's an issue with submitting the form using `document.getElementsByName('myfm')[0].submit();` and you need to debug it to figure out why it isn't triggering.

Comment: By the looks of it you might be missing a closing form tag, and you should quote all the values of the attributes, i.e. `method="POST"` instead of `method=post`

Comment: Ya,i tried that before the first comment
because my form is in PHP
`echo "<form name='myfm' method='post' action='quizz.php' id='myfm' onSubmit='return test()'>";`
I did tried the return and use ID method its still dont work

Comment: I solved it with button click
`document.getElementById("getrr").click();`